# Encrypting Client Secret for Azure Key Vault connection in application property file in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

i'm facing issues in encrypting the client secret parameter in application property file for the connection of Azure key vault with my springboot project.
For connection of a springboot project to key vault we need certain parameters to be configured for the Azure key vault.

```
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id= xxxx
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=xyzzz

spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint= abc
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=xxxx
```

How can I encrypt-decrypt this parameter "**spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret"** here only as without encryption  it would defeat the purpose of storing secrets in key vaults as the client ID and Client Secrets are exposed here.

Or any other way by which it is not visible in application.property ??

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created the service principal using below command***

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name sp_name --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/sunscription_id
```

***I have created the keyvault instance***

[image]

***I have created and stored the secret key value into the keyvault***

*Click on generate/import and give the secret & value and create the secret*

[image]

***Click on this link [springboot setup](https://start.spring.io/) to setup the springboot application***

[image]

***I run the following command to run the server***

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

***I have created the and added the keyvault configuration to the app***

*The keyvault it will allows the secrets from the application code
In the application.properties file I have added the keyvault values*

```
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=1bb32808-920f-42b4-9205-8e162b105bac
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=XXXX
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=https://springappkv.vault.azure.net/
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47
```

[image]

***I have added the import function in application.java file***

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
@Value("${connectionString}")
private String connectionString;
```

[image]

***I have deployed the azure app service***

*Added the some build in plugins in pom.xml file*

[image]

***Configured the plugin using below command***

```
mvn azure-webapp:config
```

***After the configuration the pom.xml file look like below***

[image]

***I have deployed my app into app service***

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package azure-webapp:deploy
```

[image]